# Load Map to Different variable names

Tags: javascript, lodash

Hi I get my loadash result using the following code

```
var acc = _.map(accounts, i => _.pick(i, 'id', 'number', 'transit'))
```

and get the result

```
{ id: '125658', number: '8143045', transit: '09060' }
```

Can I get the result in the following way

```
{ account_id: '125658', account_number: '8143045', account_transit: '09060' }
```

Comment: Sure, just take `acc` and remap the keys. You can do this with a simple assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strange use case for lodash. Just use native js.

```
var acc = _.map(accounts, i => ({ account_id: i.id, account_number: i.number, account_transit: i.transit }));
```